# How do you minimize $\varphi(f) = \int_y \tilde{\varphi}(f(y),y) p_y(y) dy$?

Tags: probability, optimization

I was trying to minimize the following equation (over choices of $f$):

$$\varphi(f) = \int_y \tilde{\varphi}(f(y),y) p_y(y) dy$$

where $p_y(y)$ is nonnegative and $\tilde{\varphi}(f(y),y) = \mathbb{E}_{H \sim P_{H \mid Y}}[Cost(H, f(y) = \hat{H} \mid Y = y]$ and Cost is some valid cost function (i.e. valid means that correct answers get lower costs than incorrect ones).

I was told it was clear that the way to minimize it was by minimizing *for each particular value of y*. i.e. choosing an f point by point basis. However, I was not sure of why that was true. Currently this is my intuition:

Since its a summation of positive things, we can make the total some as small as possible by making each little term in the sum as small as possible. Is this right? Is there a better intuitive/conceptual explanation? Anyone has a rigorous answer too?

However, how does this optimization problem change if $p_y(y)$ is allowed to be negative? I don't really see what is so special about $p_y(y)$ being positive.

Why can't we similarly do, if we have negative values, those points as small as possible? and the other as large as possible? How does the optimization problem change we allow negative things?

I was looking for either a rigorous proof or a intuitive/conceptual argument.

---

I have a feeling that this question is about something more general, if you know what it is, feel free to comment it (I also wanted to adapt my title to make it more searchable according to the more general concept of my question).